# Alternatives to macro substitution in java

Tags: java, macros, constants

I have a log statement in which I always use `this.getClass().getSimpleName()`as the 1st parameter.
I would like to put this in some sort of macro constant and use that in all my log statements.
But I learned that Java has no such simple mechanism unlike say C++.

What is the best way to achieve this sort of functionality in Java?

My example log statements (from Android) is as follows..

```
Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"Starting LocIden service...");
```

Comment: Are you creating these statements for debugging purposes? If so will debugger tools not help you avoid the logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java doesn't have macros but you can make your code much shorter:

```
Log.v(this, "Starting LocIden service...");
```

And in the `Log` class:

```
public void v(Object object, String s)
{
    _v(object.getClass().getSimpleName(), s);
}
```

Another approach could be to inspect the call stack.

Comment: Thanks Mark. That is much more clean :-)

Answer (score 1):

Karthik, most logging tools allow you to specify the format of the output and one of the parameters is the class name, which uses the method Mark mentioned (stack inspection)

For example, in log4j the parameter is %C to reference a class name.

Comment: Thanks for replying Augusto..I was using the "Log" utility of the Android SDK for my logging purposes. It doesn't seem to have this particular functionality available directly.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to follow what android suggests for its logging functionality.

```
Log.v(TAG, "Message");
```

where `TAG` is a private static final string in your class.

Comment: That was my initial approach but I thought I can use the class name directly, then this question popped up :)

Comment: I rather like the static final string method. That way you can change it very easily if you want it to be something other than the name of the class.

Comment: Me too but I just wanted to know if there was indeed a way to achieve something like macro substitution here. That way I can use a generic call across all my classes.

Answer (score -1):

Use a proper logging framework (e.g. slf4j). Each class that logs has its own logger, so there's no need to pass the class name to the log method call.

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

logger.debug("Starting service");
//...
logger.debug("Service started");
```